# redirecting to thankyou.aspx page after survey

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am trying to direct after user click on "Finish" on a sharepoint survey. But the following code executes when user click on "Respond to this survey". Any idea what is happening.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect()
{
  var inputcCtrls = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(var m=0; m<inputcCtrls.length; m++) 
   if(inputcCtrls[m].type=='button'&&inputcCtrls[m].value=='Finish')
     var funcOnClick = inputcCtrls[m].onclick;
         inputcCtrls[m].onclick = window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
}
redirect();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about javascript, but in c# the code block

```
var funcOnClick = inputcCtrls[m].onclick;
inputcCtrls[m].onclick = window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
```

would need to be in parenthesis as the if statement only applies to the next line of code, so the following would work

```
if(inputcCtrls[m].type=='button'&&inputcCtrls[m].value=='Finish')
{
     var funcOnClick = inputcCtrls[m].onclick;
         inputcCtrls[m].onclick = window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit thanks to graham's answer.
Change:

```
for(var m=0; m<inputcCtrls.length; m++) 
   if(inputcCtrls[m].type=='button'&&inputcCtrls[m].value=='Finish')
     var funcOnClick = inputcCtrls[m].onclick;
         inputcCtrls[m].onclick = window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
```

to

```
for(var m=0; m<inputcCtrls.length; m++) {
   if(inputcCtrls[m].type=='button'&&inputcCtrls[m].value=='Finish') {
      var funcOnClick = inputcCtrls[m].onclick;

       inputcCtrls[m].onclick = function () { window.location = "http://www.google.com/" };
   }
}
```

[onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick) wants a function. This is why I always use parathesis no matter if it's one line or not.

Comment: Nothing happens after clicking the Finish Button.

Comment: Actually, I needed space so now I can redirect. but it opens in SharePoint's newform window insead of redirecting to current window (or tab). if(inputcCtrls[m].type == 'button' && inputcCtrls[m].value == 'Finish')

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to assign a unique class name to the button and use `document.getElementsByClassName` than it is to loop through all the inputs to get the right one.

```
var inputcCtrls = document.getElementsByClassName("finalButton");
inputcCtrls[0].onclick = function() {
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
}
```

Comment: It seems SharePoint does not use class for input button. See below: <input type="button" name="ctl00$m$g_f46a290b_d993_4347_a2da_868aff18de82$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl01$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem" value="Finish"

Comment: SharePoint - argh! What a pain.